# Django - How to navigate between multiple apps

Tags: django, templates

I'm a beginner in Django and don't understand how the templates "dirs" in setup.py works
In my project directory, I have 2 apps. I want to reach them via a navigation bar.
In the Navigation bar, I have "Home" "Manipulation" "Visualization"
I can reach Home and Manipulation page, but when I try to reach the Visualization page, the browser shows me the Manipulation page again.

[image: project_dir]

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'manipulation/templates/manipulation'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'visualization/templates/visualization'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Somebody can help me please?

Thank you very much

In Dirs : [], when I swap the order and put the "Visualization" path before the "Manipulation" path, I get the Visualization page instead of the Manipulation page

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have

```
'APP_DIRS' = True,
```

django will automatically look for templates in all app_name/templates/ folders

2. point to templates always as "app_name/template_name.html"

   (which will then point to "app_name/templates/app_name/template_name.html")
3. store the templates as app_name/templates/app_name/templates_name.html"

That way you can have an individual e.g. home.html in each app without conflicts.

in 'DIRS' you should only add directories that you want to add outside the apps systematic. Currently you are overwriting the normal search in you your app folders and together with a missing "app_name/" in your "/app_name/template_name.html" you get the behavior that you describe

Comment: Thank you very much. But still the issue persist.

Comment: did you remove the os.path.join statements for the apps? please post the render command in your view.

Comment: Yes I removed them like you said. I added a [app_name]/templates/[app_name]/index.html

Comment: and the view code : `def index(request):
    return render(request, 'manipulation/index.html')`

Comment: Maybe I should erase the whole project and start one from scratch

Comment: paths sound correct - and still the "visualization/index.html" is rendered to the html page?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I did something wrong when I setup my environment. I'll try to create my app from scratch again, or I might switch to Flask, that seems to me easier to use